# Eclipse RCP4: Display HandledToolItem with both image and label

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, rcp, e4

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP 4 application and trying to add a HandledToolItem that displays both a label and an image to its left. Problem is whenever i add the image it only displays the image and hides the label. Is there any other way of getting this implemented other than creating a new ToolControl with a Button or a custom Toolbar that can handle this?

It would be nice to have the HandledToolItem because of the simpler management through Commands and Handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `FORCE_TEXT` to the Tags (on the Supplementary tab) for the HandledToolItem in the e4xmi file.